# Key mapping for putty or putty alternative

Tags: telnet, putty, key-bindings

at my work we're trying to find a replacement for an old telnet client that we use to connect to an SCO Unix server running an old program.  I have found that I can almost get putty to do everything required - setting it to SCO function keys lets me use the F1 to F12 correctly and setting the translation character set to CP437 draws all the lines correctly.

The problem is that the program we use on the server pretty much requires the use of custom key mapping.  That is we need to be able to map the home key to ";$", the end key to "exit^M", the F-10 key to ";}" etc.  Putty doesn't allow custom mapping.  We've tried to edit the source code of putty to change its behaviour, but had no luck.

Does anyone know if there is a modified version of putty somewhere that allows key binding?  Or another free terminal program that does?  Or instructions for what to change in the putty source code?  If we can't find a solution we're probably going to end up buying [ZOC](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/), but we'd rather not if we can find an open alternative.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, in the end we were able to modify the Putty source code as required to add the custom keys.